# How to apply fixpack for IBM HTTP Server for WebSphere Application Server

Tags: websphere-8, ibmhttpserver

I am trying to install Fix Pack 13 for IBM HTTP Server 8.5.5.0 on Linux. I am using a silent install.

/opt/IBM/InstallationManager/eclipse/tools/imcl input /opt/repo/response.xml -acceptLicense -sP

Here is my response file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<agent-input clean="true" temporary="true">
<server>
    <repository location='/opt/repo/IHS85513'/>
</server>
<install modify='false'>
<offering id='com.ibm.websphere.IHS.v85' 
 profile='IBM HTTP Server for WebSphere Application Server V8.5' 
 features='core.feature,arch.64bit' installFixes='all'/>
<!-- <offering id='PM12345_WAS80' profile='IBM HTTP Server for WebSphere Application Server V8.5'/> -->
</install>

<profile id='IBM HTTP Server for WebSphere Application Server V8.5' 
 installLocation='/opt/IBM/HTTPServer2'>
<data key='eclipseLocation' value='/opt/IBM/HTTPServer2'/>
<data key='user.import.profile' value='false'/>
<data key='user.ihs.httpPort' value='9082'/>
<data key='user.ihs.http.server.service.name' value='IBM HTTP Server for WebSphere Application Server V8.5'/>
<data key='user.ihs.installHttpService' value='false'/>
<data key='user.ihs.http.server.service.name.key' value='IBMHTTPServerforWebSphereApplicationServerV8.5'/>
<data key='cic.selector.nl' value='en'/>
<data key='user.ihs.allowNonRootSilentInstall' value='true'/>
</profile>
<preference name='com.ibm.cic.common.core.preferences.eclipseCache' value='/opt/IBM/IMSharedWebsphere'/>
</agent-input>
```

But i have 3 httpd server

```
/opt/IBM/HTTPServer
/opt/IBM/HTTPServer1
/opt/IBM/HTTPServer2
```

But whenever i gave installation path as /opt/IBM/HTTPServer1 or /opt/IBM/HTTPServer2 .. It got installed on /opt/IBM/HTTPServer only. Can some please guide what is the mistake?

```
                 25%                50%                75%                100%
------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
............................................................................
Updated to com.ibm.websphere.IHS.v85_8.5.5013.20180112_1418 in the /opt/IBM/HTTPServer directory.
```

Answer (score 1):

The silent option for IBM Installation Manager is really quite poor/confusing compared to just command-line.   For some reason the WebSphere docs stress it above command-line. Here is all it takes for install and update:

```
imcl install com.ibm.websphere.IHS.v90_9.0.10.20181119_1807    \
 com.ibm.java.jdk.v8_8.0.5041.20190924_1031 -repositories       \
 http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/V9WASSupplements \
 -installationDirectory /opt/IHS90 -acceptLicense \
 -secureStorageFile /home/covener/iim.storage     \
 -masterPasswordFile /home/covener/iim.password -showProgress

imcl install com.ibm.websphere.IHS.v90_9.0.5001.20190828_0616 -repositories \
 http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/V9WASSupplements             \
 -installationDirectory /opt/IHS90 -acceptLicense -secureStorageFile        \
 /home/covener/iim.storage -masterPasswordFile /home/covener/iim.password   \
 -showProgress
```

My guess for the response file error is that those installs don't share the same IIM "profile" and that's what it is keying off of. But there's just so much unnecessary data in that silent response file to worry about I wouldn't go anywhere near it.